# Javascript проблемы с замыканием

Tags: javascript

Появилась необходимость написать простой счетчик (как товары в корзине интернет магазина +- у значения input). Всегда делал примерно вот так и проблем не было, все работало (упростил чтобы видна была суть):

```
var count = 1;
input.value = count;

next.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(count < 4) {
        count++;
        input.value = count;
    }
});

prev.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (count > 1) {
        count--;
        input.value = count;
    }
});
```

Считает от 1 до 4.

Но сейчас нужно вставить счетчик в модальное окно, которое будет вызываться по нажатию на разные элементы. Счетчик будет инициализироваться в момент появления окна (поместил счетчик в функцию). На первый взгляд все срабатывает нормально, все переключается, при закрытии окна и вызове другого окна значение поля ставится в 1 (как указано в 1й строке), НО если нажать на кнопку назад сразу после появления счетчика во второй++ раз (если предыдущее окно было закрыто на числе более чем 1), то он начинает отсчет обратно с того значения, на котором было закрыто прошлое окно, игнорируя `if(count>1)`, как будто count сохраняет значение из предыдущего окна, хотя по идее я специально переназначил его в 1 на первой строке.

Хотелось бы разобраться в чем причина, по какому принципу это срабатывает и как лучше решить эту проблему?

Comment: Вопрос решился заменой addEventListener на .onclick. Видимо какая-то особенность его работы. Но первая часть вопроса "...Хотелось бы разобраться в чем причина, по какому принципу это срабатывает..." - все равно еще актуальна.

Comment: стоит лучше описывать вопрос, так как предоставляя упрощенный вариант, вы получите ответ на упрощенный вариант, а не на тот, что вам нужен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в способе назначения обработчика события. AddEventListener() может добавлять несколько обработчиков на одно событие. При повторной инициализации счетчика на событие клика добавляется еще один такой же обработчик, нарушая нормальную работу счетчика.

Answer (score 0):

У вас `count` - глобальная переменная и, соответственно, она сохраняет свое предыдущее значение. Выход - сделать ее локальной для каждой функции

```
next.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var count = input.value;
    if(count < 4) {
        count++;
        input.value = count;
    }
});

prev.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var count = input.value;
    if (count > 1) {
        count--;
        input.value = count;
    }
});
```

Comment: Она не глобальная. Это укороченный кусок кода из функции initCount(), которая вызывается при вызове модального окна. Проблема решилась просто изменением addEventListener на обычный .onclick, не трогая данную переменную. Но почему так произошло, мне все равно не ясно.

Comment: @Пупкин В вашем коде она глобальная. Мы обсуждаем ваш код, а не некоторую гипотетическую абстракцию

Comment: В описании я указал, как и откуда вызывается этот код. И, соответственно, что это не глобальная переменная.